# It tells me "expected an indent block" could someone help me?

Tags: python

```
def run():
        global var
        var = something()
for x in range(10):
        if x < 0:
        return
    from tkinter import *
    master = Tk()

    canvas_width = 2000
    canvas_height = 1000

    w = Canvas(master, 
                width=canvas_width,
                height=canvas_height)
    w.pack()

    y = int(canvas_height / 2)
    # w.create_line(0, y, canvas_width, y, fill="#476042")
    # w.Label(0, y, canvas_width, y, text="Hello Tkinter!")
    w.create_text(y, y, text="Take your shot", font="Helvetica 115 bold")
    mainloop()

    run()
```

Comment: What's the full error message?

Answer (score 3):

Try to format your code this way! Indentation is important in Python. Python expects instructions belonging to a control statement (or any statement ending in a colon) to be indented.

```
from tkinter import *

def run():
    global var
    var = something()
for x in range(10):
    if x < 0:
        return    
    master = Tk()

    canvas_width = 2000
    canvas_height = 1000

    w = Canvas(master, 
               width=canvas_width,
               height=canvas_height)
    w.pack()
    y = int(canvas_height / 2)
    # w.create_line(0, y, canvas_width, y, fill="#476042")
    # w.Label(0, y, canvas_width, y, text="Hello Tkinter!")
    w.create_text(y, y, text="Take your shot", font="Helvetica 115 bold")
    mainloop()
    run()
```

Comment: And also the `import` line should be outside the loop block

Answer (score 0):

Your code formatting is incorrect. Python expects an indented block after your if statement, and when it doesn't find it, it throws an `IndentationError`. Just indent line 6 and then it will work:

```
def run():
    global var
    var = something()
for x in range(10):
    if x < 0:
        return
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

canvas_width = 2000
canvas_height = 1000

w = Canvas(master, 
            width=canvas_width,
            height=canvas_height)
w.pack()

y = int(canvas_height / 2)
# w.create_line(0, y, canvas_width, y, fill="#476042")
# w.Label(0, y, canvas_width, y, text="Hello Tkinter!")
w.create_text(y, y, text="Take your shot", font="Helvetica 115 bold")
mainloop()

run()
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) is a short article on indentation.